# Android Q ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork with timeout shows error Dialog that stops any subsequent requests

Tags: android, kotlin, android-networking, android-developer-api

I'm using Android's `ConnectivityManager.networkRequest(..)` with a timeout to get a hold of a specific network after a queue from user input.

Everything works fine most of the time, but if I let the request timeout, I notice I get another Dialog saying

> Something came up. The application has cancelled the request to choose a device." which requires the user to manually dismiss it before we can do any other network requests.

My questions is: **How can I dismiss this dialog programmatically?** I do not want to depend on a second queue from the user before re-attempting to get a hold of the network.

And yes I know I could simply get rid of the timeout, but it serves a specific purpose on the design of the app.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Nope :/ doesn't seem to be a way of accessing that dialog programmatically as of API 30